# Building a memory game - cards in html or js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm starting to build a memory game.

I was looking at several tutorials and I find a substantial difference between people who put the cards code in the HTML:

https://marina-ferreira.github.io/projects/js/memory-game/

or the ones who use an array in the script.js:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjyDOHzKN0w

I was wondering if you can help me to understand what's the difference and why I should choose one way or the other.

Comment: Using an array would prevent repeated html code. you would only need 1 html template and your code would render the rest. its a faster and neater way, a good book to read is "Clean Code" by Robert Cecil Martin. essentially functions should only do 1 thing and repeating code is poor practice.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMano, I appreciate the reading suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

21st century single page applications have minimal HTML (Something like `<div id=app />`).
The rest would be handled by a JavaScript framework/library.

Comment: OP hasn't said anything about SPAs here, so I'm not sure what relevance this has